# Merge two dictionaries with the same keys

Tags: python

I have two dictionnaries loaded from config files, formatted like this:
`{key: (value, files_name)}`

With files_name: the files where i can find this value.

For example:

```
dict_1 = {'a': ({'b': ({'c': (1, ['file_1'])}, ['file_1'])}, ['file_1'])}
dict_2 = {'a': ({'b': ({'c': (2, ['file_2'])}, ['file_2'])}, ['file_2'])}
```

I want to merge them together, and make a concatenation of the files names list.

So basically, following the example above, the output should be:

```
{'a': ({'b': ({'c': (1, ['file_1', 'file_2'])}, ['file_1', 'file_2'])}, ['file_1', 'file_2'])}
```

Comment: We would like to see your code and help you correcting it.

Comment: I suggest using recursion. Start with the simplest example to merge two dictionaries like `{'c': (1, ['file_1'])}` and `{'c': (2, ['file_2'])}`.

Answer (score 1):

With recursion it can be done with dictionaries of any complexity, provided that the structure and the keys are the same in both dictionaries.

```
def mergedict(dd1, dd2):
    dict_res = {}
    for key, val in dd1.items():
        if isinstance(val[0], dict):
            dict_res[key] = (mergedict(val[0], dd2[key][0]), val[1] + dd2[key][1])
        else:
            dict_res[key] = (val[0], val[1] + dd2[key][1])
    return dict_res
```

So if you do:

```
rr = mergedict(dict_1, dict_2)
print(rr)
```

with your dicts you get:

```
{'a': ({'b': ({'c': (1, ['file_1', 'file_2'])}, ['file_1', 'file_2'])}, ['file_1', 'file_2'])}
```

which is your expected output.

Comment: This output is exactly what I need for this case. But what if the keys are not the same in both dictionaries ? for example:

dict_1 = `{'a': ({'b': ({'c': (1, ['my_file'], []), 'd': (3, ['my_file'], [])},
        ['my_file'],
        [])},
      ['my_file'],
      [])}
`


dict_2 = `{'a': ({'x': ('we', ['my_file'], []), 'c': (2, ['my_file'], [])},
      ['my_file'],
      []),
     'e': ({'f': (22, ['my_file'], []), 'ok': ('ok', ['my_file'], [])},
      ['my_file'],
      [])}
`

Comment: What do you want in that case? An intersection of the common keys or an union?

Comment: I would like something like this:
`res = {'a': ({'b': ({'c': (1, ['file_1']}, file), 'x': (value, file)}, file)}`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is close to what you're looking for. Though this is an assumption without seeing your code:

```
dict_1 = {'a': ({'b': ({'c': (1, ['file_1'])}, ['file_1'])}, ['file_1'])}
dict_2 = {'a': ({'b': ({'c': (2, ['file_2'])}, ['file_2'])}, ['file_2'])}

ds = [dict_1, dict_2]

d = {}

for k in dict_1.iterkeys():
    d[k] = tuple(d[k] for d in ds)

print d

>> {'a': (({'b': ({'c': (1, ['file_1'])}, ['file_1'])}, ['file_1']),
  ({'b': ({'c': (2, ['file_2'])}, ['file_2'])}, ['file_2']))}
```

Comment: "I believe this is close to what you're looking for." - did you even bother to read my text...

Comment: I disagree with your text. This is **not** close to what the OP wants.

Comment: provide an answer yourself then instead of penalizing others that are actually trying to provide some input